Analytic continuation of distribution using series expansion
One can show the following distributional identity:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \left(\frac{1}{\epsilon^2+|\vec{x}|^2}\right)^\Delta 
        &= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \dfrac{a_m}{\epsilon^{2\Delta-n-2m}}\Box^m \delta^{(n)}(\vec{x})+\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{b_m}{\epsilon^{\Delta-2m}}\operatorname{Pv}\left[\dfrac{1}{|\vec{x}|^{2m+2}}\right]
    \end{split},\quad \vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n\tag{1}
\end{equation}
where there are explicit expressions for $a_m$ and $b_m$ in terms of gamma functions which are not necessary for this question. Here $\Box$ is the Laplace operator in $\mathbb{R}^n$. This identity is supposed to hold in the distributional sense, in other words, when both sides are applied to some test function $\phi\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. In particular, $\operatorname{Pv}$ stands for the principal value as usual.
Now, my question is on the analytic structure of both sides, considering that we would like to analytically continue in $\epsilon$. The result (1) is valid for $\epsilon>0$ and I want to study the possible continuations to $\epsilon =i\varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon>0$.
The point is the following, however. If we view the LHS as a function of a complex variable $\epsilon\in \mathbb{C}$, it has a branch point at $\epsilon = \pm i|\vec{x}|$. There is no branch point at $\epsilon =0$ o n the other hand.
But on the RHS we have a series where each term of the series has a branch point at $\epsilon =0$ but no branch point at $\epsilon = \pm i|\vec{x}|$. So when we choose some path to do analytic continuation on the LHS the result depends on the winding numbers about $\epsilon = \pm i|\vec{x}|$, while on the RHS the result depends on the winding number about $\epsilon =0$ only.
What is going on? Why it seems that working with the LHS or the RHS is different to perform analytic continuation in this case? What is the correct way to reconcile this and to perform analytic continuation of equation (1) to imaginary $\epsilon$?

How did you get (1), was it just a Taylor series in $\epsilon$ ? What is $z$ and $\Box$? In general this is an issue of radius of convergence. For example a Taylor expansion of a function where it is analytic will have analytic terms but the function can present branch points outside the disk of convergence.

The $z$ was a typo, it should be $x$. The $\Box$ is just the Laplace operator on $\mathbb{R}^n$. There are a couple of ways to get (1). One is to integrate the LHS against a test function $\phi(x)$ and split the integration into an open ball of radius $\zeta$ and its complement. Then you can Taylor expand both integrals in $\epsilon$, the one containing the origin gives the delta function series and the other gives the principal value series (the principal value comes from the $\zeta\to 0$ limit.

Another option is to Fourier transform the LHS writing it as a Mellin transform. Then the Fourier transform is given by a Bessel function, which expanded in $\epsilon$ generates two series. When Fourier transformed back these two series are the ones in (1).
